# Are search-based sites bad for SEO, and should I link to all posts instead?

Tags: seo, google, search, forms

I would like to pitch a scenario. The front page of my site is a search box and a button which links to a post form. I allow users to post content on the post form which is then searchable from the front page search box.

However, the front page is only a search box, and the only way Google can find the posted content is through the *sitemap.xml* rather than following content links on the front page (as if the posts were listed on the front page along with the search form).

1. Is this bad SEO, since google can't really use the search form.
2. Would my site have improved SEO by having a link on the front page stating "List all posts" where they can all be found without having to use the search box.

In a more general way, can you SEO a site which has original content who's front page looks like a search engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. Although [Google can submit some forms](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html) they generally do not do so. So any content that is only available via a form submission should be assumed to be hidden from search engines.
2. Yes. This is functionally the same as an HTML sitemap.

You can also submit an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) (although [they don't guarantee crawling](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just a quick note though, if google an find it through the xml site map does it really need it through the html sitemap as it were?

Comment: Technically Google only needs to find it once and it doesn't matter how. But oyu need to make sure they do find it once. Since XML sitemaps so do not guarantee crawling, having and HTML sitemap is always a good idea.